# Store std::string into int[] for Big Integer in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

I'm trying to create my own class for BigInteger values. In this class Big Integer consist of `unsigned int ints[capacity]`, and I have following code to convert `std::string` into `BigInteger`:

```
void FromByteString1(const std::string& buf) {
    int mask[] = {0, 8, 16, 24};
    int validMask = 0xff;
    size_t currentMask = 0, currentIndex = 0;
    for (register size_t i = 0; i < buf.size(); ++i) {
        int tmp = (int) buf[i];
        data[currentIndex] |= ((tmp << mask[currentMask]) & (validMask << mask[currentMask]));
        if (++currentMask == 4) {
            currentMask = 0;
            ++currentIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

I trying to resolve this problem using `union { char[4] chars; int value; }`, but it gives me nothing.

Here is my output:

[image]

Here is full code of test project "Convertor", which is created to resolve this issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <bitset>

#define Write(message) std::cout << message
#define WriteLine(message) std::cout << message << std::endl
#define WriteEndl() std::cout << std::endl

#define WIDTH_STR 9
#define WIDTH_INT 33

void ShowStringChars(const std::string& str) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
        Write( std::setw(WIDTH_STR) << str[i] );
    WriteEndl();
}

void ShowStringCodes(const std::string& str) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
        Write( std::setw(WIDTH_STR) << (int)str[i] );
    WriteEndl();
}

void ShowStringCodesBin(const std::string& str) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        std::bitset<8> bites( (int)str[i] );
        Write( std::setw(WIDTH_STR) << bites );
    }
    WriteEndl();
}

void ShowIntValues(int* arr, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        Write( std::setw(WIDTH_INT) << arr[i] );
    WriteEndl();
}

void ShowIntValuesBin(int* arr, size_t length) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        std::bitset<32> bites( arr[i] );
        Write( std::setw(WIDTH_INT) << bites );
    }
    WriteEndl();
}

const int capacity = 256;
int data[capacity];

void Clear() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < capacity; ++i)
        data[i] = 0;
}

union its {
    char chars[4];
    int value;
} int_to_str;

void FromByteString1(const std::string& buf) {
    int mask[] = {0, 8, 16, 24};
    int validMask = 0xff;
    size_t currentMask = 0, currentIndex = 0;
    for (register size_t i = 0; i < buf.size(); ++i) {
        int tmp = (int) buf[i];
        data[currentIndex] |= ((tmp << mask[currentMask]) & (validMask << mask[currentMask]));
        if (++currentMask == 4) {
            currentMask = 0;
            ++currentIndex;
        }
    }
}

void FromByteString2(const std::string& buf) {
    size_t index = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < buf.size(); i += 4, ++index) {

        int_to_str.chars[0] = buf[i + 0];
        int_to_str.chars[1] = buf[i + 1];
        int_to_str.chars[2] = buf[i + 2];
        int_to_str.chars[3] = buf[i + 3];

        data[index] = int_to_str.value;
    }
}

int main() {

    Clear();

    //std::string value = "this is some string";
    std::string value = "this str";

    ShowStringChars(value);
    ShowStringCodes(value);
    ShowStringCodesBin(value);

    WriteEndl();
    WriteEndl();
    WriteEndl();

    FromByteString1(value);

    ShowIntValues(data, value.length() / 4);
    ShowIntValuesBin(data, value.length() / 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Did anyone had similar problem? Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Why are you not using your debugger?  Debugging is part of the process of learning how to write programs.

Comment: note that register isn't a valid keyword in C++ anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The streaming operator of bitset uses `std::bitset::to_string` which behaves like this:

> The resulting string contains N characters with the first character corresponds to the last (N-1th) bit and the last character corresponding to the first bit.

So, the last (rightmost) character of the output is the least significant (first) bit.

The first byte that you read, you shift the least. Therefore it becomes the least significant byte. Therefore the first byte that you read into the integer will be the right most byte in the output of the bitset.

A solution: Reverse the order in which you read the bytes i.e. interpret the input buffer as little endian, rather than big endian.

---

Note that since bitset prints highest bit first, you could interpret the output as little endian with individual bytes reversed, or big endian with the entire set reversed. I use reversed here in relation to memory position that grows left to right.

PS. representing a big integer as a null terminated string is not very useful since there is no way to represent numbers that contain bytes with the value zero.